# How to add different colors to every word that have capital letter?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, regex, css-selectors

How to add different colors to every word that starts with a capital letter?

Example:`Justin` `Creative` `Design` `Develope`

This my code

```js
 var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
    this.toRotate = toRotate;
    this.el = el;
    this.loopNum = 0;
    this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
    this.txt = '';
    this.tick();
    this.lastDeletingStatus=0;
    this.isDeleting = 0;
};
var timer;
TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
    var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
    var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

    if (this.isDeleting===1) {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
    } else {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
    }

    this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

    var that = this;
    var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

    if (this.isDeleting===1) { delta /= 2; }

    if (this.isDeleting===0 && this.txt === fullTxt) {
        delta = this.period;
        this.isDeleting = 1;
    } else if (this.isDeleting===1 && this.txt === '') {
        this.isDeleting = 0;
        this.loopNum++;
        delta = 500;
    }

    if(this.isDeleting!==2){
    timer=setTimeout(function() {
     that.tick();
        }, delta);
    }
};

TxtType.prototype.toggleStart=function(){
//start back up 
    if(this.isDeleting===2){
        this.isDeleting=this.lastDeletingStatus;
        this.lastDeletingStatus=2;
 }
//stop
else{
    this.lastDeletingStatus=this.isDeleting;
    this.isDeleting=2;
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
}
    var toggleStart=function(){
       txtType.toggleStart();
        txtType.tick();
    }
 var txtType;

    window.onload = function() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
        for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
            var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
            var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
            if (toRotate) {
  txtType=new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
            }
          
        }
        // INJECT CSS
        var css = document.createElement("style");
        css.type = "text/css";
        css.innerHTML = ".typewrite > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #fff}";
        document.body.appendChild(css);
    };
```

```css
body {
    background-color:#ce3635;
    text-align: center;
     color:#fff;
     padding-top:10em;
     font-family:Helvetica;
 }

* { color:#fff; text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<div class="type-wrap">
<h2>
  <a href="" class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "Hi, my name is Justin.", "I am Creative.", "I love Design with CSS.", "I love to Develop with javascript." ]'>
    <span class="wrap"></span></a>
</h2>
  
</div>
```

Comment: You'd need to wrap the words in question in a span and then apply styling to that span. Maybe add spans to the whole sentence as required first, then update the code that prints it one letter at a time to deal with the nested spans.

Comment: And check first character of word is same as that character upper cased

Comment: If you wrote this, that should be simple for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to the `tick()` function:

```
  var rgx = /\b([A-Z].*?)\b/g;
  var rep = `<span class='cap'>$1</span>`;
  var fullTxt = fullTxt.replace(rgx, rep);
```

What this does is it takes the string `fullTxt` and uses `replace()` and a regex to replace any match (a word that starts with an uppercase letter) with the same word wrapped:

`<span class='cap'>`**Word**`</span>`

Also don't forget to declare `.cap` class `color` property and value to CSS.

### Demo

```js
var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
  this.toRotate = toRotate;
  this.el = el;
  this.loopNum = 0;
  this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
  this.txt = '';
  this.tick();
  this.lastDeletingStatus = 0;
  this.isDeleting = 0;
};
var timer;
TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
  var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
  var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];
  var rgx = /\b([A-Z].*?)\b/g;
  var rep = `<span class='cap'>$1</span>`;
  var fullTxt = fullTxt.replace(rgx, rep);

  if (this.isDeleting === 1) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
  } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
  }

  this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + this.txt + '</span>';

  var that = this;
  var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

  if (this.isDeleting === 1) {
    delta /= 2;
  }

  if (this.isDeleting === 0 && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = 1;
  } else if (this.isDeleting === 1 && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = 0;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 500;
  }

  if (this.isDeleting !== 2) {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      that.tick();
    }, delta);
  }
};

TxtType.prototype.toggleStart = function() {
  //start back up 
  if (this.isDeleting === 2) {
    this.isDeleting = this.lastDeletingStatus;
    this.lastDeletingStatus = 2;
  }
  //stop
  else {
    this.lastDeletingStatus = this.isDeleting;
    this.isDeleting = 2;
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
}
var toggleStart = function() {
  txtType.toggleStart();
  txtType.tick();
}
var txtType;

window.onload = function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
    var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
    if (toRotate) {
      txtType = new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
    }

  }
  // INJECT CSS
  var css = document.createElement("style");
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.innerHTML = ".typewrite > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #fff}";
  document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ce3635;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10em;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

* {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cap {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="type-wrap">
  <h2>
    <a href="" class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "Hi, my name is Justin.", "I am Creative.", "I love Design with CSS.", "I love to Develop with javascript." ]'>
      <span class="wrap"></span></a>
  </h2>

</div>
```

Comment: Great, but while running animation I see a tag `<` before the word. How to remove that in order to smooth?

Comment: Yeah, that's unavoidable AFAIK, the text rendered in HTML needs to be wrapped in an element if it's inline with other text that has different styles. The nature of your app shows each letter typed so there's the problem. As the next letter is typed after a bracket, it disappears and causes that jerky motion. I did a little update: 1. the `<span>` is now a `<mark>` without a class that helps since there's less markup to type.  2. decreased the delta variable from 500 to 200.

Comment: Good idea, I instead use `<i>` is faster.

Comment: Make sure you add `.wrap i {font-style:normal}` unless you want your Uppercase words to be italicized.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the string to a function, split it at the spaces to give words, compare the first character of each word with the uppercase version of that character and if it matches - apply a span with a class that cna be colored. return the string to the inner HTML of a display element. To applyy different colours - either select a different class (each of which has a different colour set) for each instance of a capitalised word, or set a random colour for the span.

Note that I have not directly used your code - but put together a little generic function.

```js
applyStyling('Hi, my name is Justin.')

function applyStyling(str) {
  let newStr='';
  let colors = ['red','orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo' , 'violet'];
  
  let strPortions=str.split(' ');
  strPortions.forEach(function(portion) {
    let firstLetter = portion.charAt(0);
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    firstLetter === firstLetter.toUpperCase()
      ? newStr += '<span class="' + colors[randomNumber] + '">' + portion + ' </span>'
      : newStr += portion + ' ' ;
  })

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = newStr;
}
```

```css
.red { color: red;}
.orange { color: orange;}
.yellow { color: yellow;}
.green { color: green;}
.blue { color: blue;}
.indigo { color: indigo;}
.violet { color: violet;}
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```